# React message not displaying after flask response

Tags: reactjs, flask

I'm following the example here: https://github.com/auth0-blog/auth0-react-sample.

I've set up a backend flask server so that when I hit the endpoint "/api/get_timestamp/" it returns the current time. This part works fine (validated in browser).

I'm trying to get it to show up in the code below but the `message` doesn't display. I know react receives it because if I do a console.log of the `responseData` in the first try catch block it works just fine.

Can someone please advise? Perhaps `const [message, setMessage] = useState("");` is not being used appropriate (though that's straight from the example).

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

const ExternalApi = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const serverUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL;

  const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();

  const callApi = async () => {
    try {
      console.log(`${serverUrl}/api/get_timestamp`)
      const response = await fetch(`${serverUrl}/api/get_timestamp`);

      const responseData = await response.json();
      
      setMessage(responseData.message);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("I am in error");
      setMessage(error.message);
    }
  };

  const callSecureApi = async () => {
    try {
      const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();

      const response = await fetch(
        `${serverUrl}/api/messages/protected-message`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        }
      );

      const responseData = await response.json();

      setMessage(responseData.message);
    } catch (error) {
      setMessage(error.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>External API</h1>
      <p>
        Use these buttons to call an external API. The protected API call has an
        access token in its authorization header. The API server will validate
        the access token using the Auth0 Audience value.
      </p>
      <div
        className="btn-group mt-5"
        role="group"
        aria-label="External API Requests Examples"
      >
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={callApi}>
          Get Public Message
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-primary"
          onClick={callSecureApi}
        >
          Get Protected Message
        </button>
      </div>
      {message && (
        <div className="mt-5">
          <h6 className="muted">Result</h6>
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
              <code className="col-12 text-light bg-dark p-4">{message}</code>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ExternalApi;
```

Below is the flask app if it is helpful:

```
# save this as app.py
from flask import Flask
import time
from datetime import datetime
from flask_cors import CORS
import json


app = Flask(__name__)
#CORS(app)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello, World!"

@app.route("/api/get_timestamp")
def get_timestamp():
    now = datetime.now()
    # dd/mm/YY H:M:S
    dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    return(json.dumps(dt_string))
    #return(dt_string)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="localhost", port=4050, debug=True)
```

Comment: @SangeetAgarwal sorry, why the & in the beginning? Mind writing out the whole block? Still figuring out react….

Answer (score 0):

Simple and silly fix:

In flask, it's returning a literal json string. So I changed it to dict so it has a "message" key.  The `get_timestamp()` function now returns:

```
return({"message": dt_string})
```